# Nao consigo utilizar o retorno json em php

Tags: php, json, api

Bom dia pessoal, estou com seguinte problema, usando um api php.

Faço uma chamada que me retorna :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí quando dou um echo var_dump() diz ser string(27398) , de depois faço json_decode() e faço um print_r(var_dump( ) ); e diz NULL , então, estou com as duvidas seguintes duvidas,  por que quando chamo o json ele vem para variável mas fica intocável quando faço objeto->offers por exemplo? Mas acho que é porque vira NULL, mas se for porque o objeto que na requisição apresenta um json na forma de string está transformando em NULL? Aguardo ajuda de vocês. E muito obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que algum caracter não utf-8 no json está quebrando seu json_decode.

Tente da seguinte forma:

> $json = json_decode(utf8_encode($jsonString), true);

Você também pode ver qual erro que ocorreu com seu json_decode usando a função json_last_error() caso a versão do php seja 5.3 ou posterior.

Sendo que:

```
JSON_ERROR_NONE - Não ocorreu nenhum erro    
JSON_ERROR_DEPTH - A profundidade máxima da pilha foi excedida   
JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH - JSON inválido ou mal formado     
JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR - Erro de caractere de controle, possivelmente codificado incorretamente    
JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX - Erro de sintaxe  
JSON_ERROR_UTF8 - caracteres UTF-8 malformado , possivelmente codificado incorretamente
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!